# ECS with ALB and SSL certificate issue: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-alb

I have an aws ECS setup and using ALB for the load balancer. The container task is running on port 8080. I have also added an `HTTPS listener` with SSL Certificate from ACM, which *forwards* the requests to the container.

Now I have one issue here. When using curl or postman to contact the load balancer's DNS name, I get the response from the app perfectly. But when using the very same DNS name in my frontend and running in frontend app locally (localhost:3000), and the request is generated from Chrome I get the following error:
`net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

How can I resolve this issue?

I also tried deploying the app to my test env, so instead of `localhost`, I have `https://example.com` which now matches the Domain name of the Certificate `(*.example.com)`. But still same results.

Comment: Can you post the complete output of curl -vvv "URL" here?

Comment: I get this now:
curl: (35) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.